# Font TU/FontAwesome(0)/m/n/10.95=FontAwesome at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found

Tags: fontawesome

I am trying to build the resume tex file https://github.com/zheyuye/resume-chinese using texlive 2023 in macOS, the build process shows error:

```
 I can't find file `FontAwesome'. <*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: FontAwesome.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome' failed to make FontAwesome.tfm.
kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation F for FontAwesome. /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)
kpathsea: Running mktexmf FontAwesome
! I can't find file `FontAwesome'. <*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. <*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: FontAwesome.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome' failed to make FontAwesome.tfm.
kpathsea: Running mktextfm FontAwesome
/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation F for FontAwesome. /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input FontAwesome
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded base=mf)
```

I have already installed the FontAwesome in macOS 13.2 like this:

```
sudo tlmgr install fontawesome
```

why still could not found the fontawesome when compile? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the installed info:

```
> tlmgr info --list fontawesome

package:     fontawesome
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Font containing web-related icons
longdesc:    The package offers access to the large number of web-related icons provided by the included font. The package requires the package, fontspec, if run with XeTeX or LuaTeX.
installed:   Yes
revision:    48145
sizes:       doc: 273k, run: 481k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 4.6.3.2
cat-license: lppl1.3
cat-topics:  font font-supp-symbol font-symbol font-otf font-type1
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex
collection:  collection-fontsextra
Included files, by type:
run files:
  texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomeone.enc
  texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesomethree.enc
  texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesometwo.enc
  texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/fontawesome/fontawesome.map
  texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.tfm
  texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.pfb
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-generic.tex
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesomesymbols-xeluatex.tex
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomeone.fd
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesomethree.fd
  texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/ufontawesometwo.fd
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/fontawesome/README.md details="Readme"
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.pdf details="Package documentation"
  texmf-dist/doc/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome.tex
```